# Convert response to JSON response standard in Nestjs

Tags: json, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem converting the result of my object after saving it to the database, because I tried to follow the recommendations of https://jsonapi.org/ and convert my answers to the Json standard.

The implementation I did is not the best. This is:

```
  async findAll() {
    const data = new DataResponse<Product>();
    return await this.repository.find().then(value => {
      data.data = value;
      data.isError = false;
      data.message = "";
      data.statusCode = 1;

      return data;
    }).catch(e => {
      const error: HttpException = e;
      data.data = [];
      data.isError = true;
      data.message = error.message;
      data.statusCode = error.getStatus();

      return data;
    });
  }
```

My json response I have this is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Oreo",
        "price": "6.5",
        "category": "Oreo",
        "stock": 50,
        "createDate": "2021-10-28T14:11:47.454Z",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2021-10-28T14:11:47.454Z"
    },
    "message": "",
    "statusCode": 1,
    "isError": false
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An alternative to the implementation that I make in my service, because I think it is very repetitive to instantiate an object of type response every time I need to return data in a @Get ()

Answer (score 0):

why not to make a DTO or initalize and object of entity like new Product(),
and then assign values if you want to save them in Database rather than stringified JSON Objects?. this would resolve your problem.